# Is there any Swing API , Component or Sample Projects to Manage Spring Security Settings?

Tags: security, spring, swing, user-interface

I'm working on a swing application and trying to merge it into Spring Framework.
fortunately every thing works in its basic mode.

but now I need a Swing-Based GUI to manage security stuff like Creating a new user, assign a user to a group ,.....

is there any Existing open source API or Swing Component which can help me?

I'm using

1. Extended DaoAuthenticationProvider & JdbcDaoImpl for Authentication.
2. UnanimousBased accessDecisionVoter & RoleVoter for Authorization
3. Simple MySql Database with Standard Tables(authorities,groups,users,..)

you know , I'm thinking of "if I use all things in their standard form, there might be some opensource implementations to handle a standard Userinterface"

thanks for any information
Moein

Comment: Hey Moein, just wondering if you can share your "basic mode swing application + spring framework" ? I am trying to do the same thing that you did. maybe upload to github or send to dondonakal@gmail.com ? many thanks